# How to compare multiple Kendall's tau results?

Tags: meta-analysis, ranking, kendall-tau

Looking for a bit of help on how to "aggregate" Kendall's Tau values from a meta-analysis

To offer a conceptual view of the data: let's say I have 40 different "studies" that each consist of 5 different experiments. It may look like this:

```
+----------+---------------+---------+----------------+
| study_id | experiment_id | outcome | other_variable |  
+----------+---------------+---------+----------------+
|      001 | A             |    83.2 |           40.2 |  
|      001 | B             |    75.2 |           24.5 |  
|      001 | C             |    78.4 |           22.4 |  
|      001 | D             |     80. |           38.2 |  
|      002 | A             |    91.2 |           40.6 |  
|      002 | B             |    54.2 |           45.2 |  
|      002 | C             |    80.5 |           49.5 |  
|      002 | D             |    78.9 |           38.5 |  
+----------+---------------+---------+----------------+
```

I want to understand if the ordinal ranking of `experiment_ids` within a given `study_id` as calculated by the `outcome` variable is similar to the same ranking as calculated by the `other_variable`. Basically, this:

```
+----------+---------------+---------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
| study_id | experiment_id | outcome | other_variable | outcome_rank | other_variable_rank |
+----------+---------------+---------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
|      001 | A             |    83.2 |           40.2 | 1            | 1                   |
|      001 | B             |    75.2 |           24.5 | 4            | 3                   |
|      001 | C             |    78.4 |           22.4 | 3            | 4                   |
|      001 | D             |    80.0 |           38.2 | 2            | 2                   |
|      002 | A             |    91.2 |           40.6 | 1            | 3                   |
|      002 | B             |    54.2 |           45.2 | 4            | 2                   |
|      002 | C             |    80.5 |           49.5 | 2            | 1                   |
|      002 | D             |    78.9 |           38.5 | 3            | 4                   |
+----------+---------------+---------+----------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

My hunch is that I'd want to use Kendall's tau to do compare the ranking between the two, which I am not sure how I would "aggregate" the findings across `study_ids`. Can anyone offer a helpful pointers as to where to begin?

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to compute the Pearson correlation within study and then convert it using Fisher's transformation into $z$ and compute the standard error. You can then uses those as a summary for each study id and meta-analyse them using inverse variance weighting in the standard way. However with only four observations within each study the standard errors are going to be large and your results will be imprecise but at least you will have a summary estimate. If you want to persist with Kendall's $\tau$ you will need to find a formula for normalising it as well as finding the standard error for that. I am not aware of such a thing but it may exist.